# are background and setBackgroundColor the same

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

If I set the color in the xml like such:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/borderForList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/default_border_color" >
```

I get my color. If I do it in code:

```
m_border.setBackgroundColor(R.color.default_border_color);
```

The color is different.  Are these methods the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
m_border.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.default_border_color));
```

R.color.default_border_color is a resource integer in R file which is generated by android automatically, `setBackgroundColor()` expects a color integer, so you must convert it by calling `getResources().getColor()` method.

see

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same.

For the [background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground) the following are equivalent:

```
android:background="@color/default_border_color" 

public void setBackgroundResource(int resid)
```

So you can set the background *resource* (`drawable`, `color` ..etc.) in either in `xml` or in the java code.

As for the [backgroundcolor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29), there seems to be no xml attribute (such as `android:backgroundcolor`) but a public method:

```
public void setBackgroundColor (int color)
```